# how can i redirect correctly to routes with GoRouter?

Tags: flutter, dart, session, redirect, flutter-go-router

how can i redirect correctly to routes ?

My application has to have some route security and I try to do it with GoRouter
but it always executes one more redirection and always returns to home.

There are only 3 secure routes (profile, order, favorites) and if you are not logged in you must go back to login.

But when I put any of the 3 routes in the url, it redirects me to the login and immediately to the home (this is what should not happen)

Can somebody help me?
I changed the logic several times but I always come back to the same point.

```
class AppRouter {
  final SessionCubit sessionCubit;

  GoRouter get router => _goRouter;

  AppRouter(this.sessionCubit);

  late final GoRouter _goRouter = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(sessionCubit.stream),
    initialLocation: APP_PAGE.home.toPath,
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: APP_PAGE.home.toPath,
        name: APP_PAGE.home.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => MyHomePage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: APP_PAGE.login.toPath,
        name: APP_PAGE.login.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: APP_PAGE.profile.toPath,
        name: APP_PAGE.profile.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => MyProfile(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: APP_PAGE.page1.toPath,
        name: APP_PAGE.page1.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const Page1(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: APP_PAGE.error.toPath,
        name: APP_PAGE.error.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(error: state.extra.toString()),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: APP_PAGE.page2.toPath,
        name: APP_PAGE.page2.toName,
        builder: (context, state) => const Page2(),
      ),        
    ],
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    errorBuilder: (context, state) => ErrorPage(error: state.error.toString()),
    redirect: (context, state) {
  
      final userAutheticated = sessionCubit.state is Authenticated;
      if (userAutheticated) {
        if (state.subloc == '/login') return '/home';
        if (state.subloc == '/profile') return '/profile';
        if (state.subloc.contains('/page1')) return '/page1';
        return '/home';
      } else {
        if (state.subloc == '/home') {
          return '/home';
        }
        if (state.subloc == '/page2') {
          return '/page2';
        } else {
          return '/login';
        }    
       
      }
    },
  );
}
```

***UPDATE 05/11***
I find the solution.

**First** -> use the last version of go_router 5.1.5 (the redirect issue is on the older versions).

**Second** -> I modify the redirect logic:

```
if(!userAutheticated && !onloginPage && !onpublicPage1 && !onPublicPage2 && !onPublicPageN){
        return '/login';
      }
      if (userAutheticated && onloginPage) {
        return '/home';
      }
      //you must include this. so if condition not meet, there is no redirect
      return null;
```

Note: I don't know why flutter web debug mode doesn't work properly. So I run the project on release mode and Voilá, it's works!.

Thanks So Much for the help!!!

Answer (score 4):

just check if your user is authenticated and not in login page, then redirect. you dont need to redirect if you user already login :

```
    final bool userAutheticated = sessionCubit.state is Authenticated;

    final bool onloginPage = state.subloc == '/login';
    

    if(!userAutheticated && !onloginPage){
      return '/login';
    }
    if(userAutheticated && onloginPage){
      return 'home';
    }
    //you must include this. so if condition not meet, there is no redirect
    return null;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The location /home and others no securized redirect always.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in `return '/home';` you need to put `return null` instead.

Because you handled all redirection for the authenticated user, so no need for another one, you just tell the router to stop redirecting (when all the conditions are not triggered) by returning null.

> Blockquote

```
     if (userAutheticated) {
        if (state.subloc == '/login') return '/home';
        if (state.subloc == '/profile') return '/profile';
        if (state.subloc.contains('/page1')) return '/page1';
     >> return '/home';
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `initialLocation` to login

```dart
  late final GoRouter _goRouter = GoRouter(
    refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(sessionCubit.stream),
    // Change initialLocation to login
    initialLocation: APP_PAGE.home.toPath,
```

Comment: But the login is not the home page, the main page is another. The login is only required to visit the profile, orders and favorites pages in case the user is not logged in.
But the home and product pages are public pages.

Answer (score -2):

The sample in the following link can help you resolve that;

[go_router](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Redirection-topic.html)

```
<pre>
 final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(routes: <RouteBase>[
  GoRoute(
  redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    // if (AuthState.of(context).isSignedIn) {
      return '/join_us';
    // } else {
    //   return null;
    // }
  },
  path: '/',
  builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const HomePage();
  },
</pre>
```